# When dividing into a small negative number I just get 0

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf, type-conversion

In my current program I am having an issue where, when I divide a number by a larger number I am just given 0. For example if I divide -272 by 400 I receive 0.

```
y=x/400;
printf("%f\n", y);
```

This is the only piece of code causing issues. x is a negative integer 1-500 and y is initialized as a float.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please show the declarations of x and y

Comment: You need to cast `x` as `float` or divide by `400.0`

Comment: if i had a coin for every int arithmetic operations expected to work as float...

Comment: @ChrisO Thanks, have solved the problem.

Comment: I cover your question and many more situations that you probably should learn about here: http://devproconnections.com/development/c-sharp-code-writing-tips-eric-lippert-math -- The article is about C# but applies to C and many other languages as well.

Comment: If both operands of `/` are of type `int`, it's an integer division with a result of type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write something like this y = x/400.0f or y = (float)x / 400

Answer (score 2):

The division operation deduces it's result based on the operands. If both operands are `int` then the result is `int`. In your case both `x` and `400` are `int` so the result of `/` is int. This `int` is then converted to `float` because `y` is float, but the result was already truncated to `int`.

You need to convert at least one operand to float:

```
y = (float) x / 400;
```

or

```
y = x / 400.0f
```